# cookies not visible from external link to php page

Tags: php, cookies

I have a PHP webpage (let's say https::xxx.com/page1.php) that uses cookies.

When I go to that page - I can see the PHP can see the cookies (`$_COOKIE['xxx']`), but when I click on a link from a [yahoo] email to the same page, I can see PHP cannot see them; if I click F5 to refresh the page - they are still not visible to PHP, but if I were to click on the location-bar and press return then the cookies become visible to PHP.

If I click on a similar link from within the xxx.com domain, I see that the cookies are visible to PHP.

There's very little to say about the code...

```
 <?php
        foreach ($_COOKIE as $k=> $v) echo "<LI>$k=$v";
 ?>
```

and the javascript that sets the cookie earlier...

```
function setCookie(name, value) {
    var expires = "";
    var days=9999;
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
    expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();

    var val = (value || "") + expires + "; secure; path=/; samesite=strict";
    document.cookie = name + "=" + val;
}
```

(the cookies I'm using are set earlier in the site, and have a Domain = "xxx.com", an expiry date many years ahead, Secure, and SameSite=Strict).

Can anyone explain what is going on?
Thanks

Comment: How should anybody help you with code, when you don't provide anything. Neither reading nor setting cookies?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite, https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks CBroe, it looks like that gave me the clue - SameSite=Strict was causing this problem.

```
function setCookie(name, value, samesite) {
   if ( samesite==undefined ) samesite='lax';   <--------------- strict, lax or none
   var days=9999;
   var date = new Date();
   date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
   var expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();

   var val = (value || "") + expires + "; secure; path=/; samesite="+samesite;
   document.cookie = name + "=" + val;
}
```